# Setting delegate to the parent of pushed scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, delegates

In my HelloWorldLayer code I am pushing a SettingsLayer scene onto the stack.

```
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[SettingsLayer scene]]];
```

The SettingsLayer needs to call a delegate method implemented in the HelloWorldLayer. But I am at a lost as to how I can set the HelloWorldLayer as the SettingsLayer's delegate. Can someone show me the proper pattern for this? I tried alloc-init of the SettingsLayer, and setting the delegate before the pushscene but this did not work.

Comment: " I tried alloc-init of the SettingsLayer, and setting the delegate before the pushscene " 
this part should work. Don't know why it is not working for you. 
Try passing your delegate object in that static scene method and set delegate there.

Comment: Had no luck with the following:         SettingsLayer *mySettingsLayer = [[SettingsLayer alloc] init];
        mySettingsLayer.delegate = self;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[[mySettingsLayer class] scene]]];

Comment: Show the code of your failed attempt so we get a chance to point out any more or less obvious wrongliness of the code. Just saying "it did not work" deprives us of the chance of correcting ... err, helping you. ;)

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting comment. Have an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
SettingsLayer *mySettingsLayer = [[SettingsLayer alloc] init]; 
mySettingsLayer.delegate = self; 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 
                                 scene:[[mySettingsLayer class] scene]]];
```

The problem is in the last line:

```
[[mySettingsLayer class] scene]
```

This creates a new instance of the `SettingsLayer` class which has no delegate set (it will be nil). The `mySettingsLayer` you created before isn't actually presented as a scene, it goes out of scope and deallocates (assuming you are using ARC, if not, this would actually leak the `mySettingsLayer` object).

To fix it pass in your already existing `mySettingsLayer` instance:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 
                                 scene:mySettingsLayer]];
```

Comment: This worked thank you. To get rid of a warning in the pushScene I had to caste mySettingsLayer as a (CCScene *).  So this means I don't need to use the conventional (?) "+scene" method at all? I am simply using the cclayer directly and casting it as a scene?

Comment: If you need to cast it it means your SettingsLayer class does not inherit from CCScene. The +scene method is just a convenience method that does alloc/init/(autorelease) for you.

Comment: My point being, the HelloWorldLayer design pattern creates a CCLayer object from alloc-init. The convenience class method (+scene) takes that layer, adds it to a scene and returns a CCScene. But my delegate property lives in the CCLayer. If we were sticking with the HelloWorldLayer pattern, I think I would access the delegate property accessing the layer as a child of the scene.

Comment: just create a ccscene after creating the layer, set the layer deletate, addchild layer to scene, push scene all in the same method